# A question about iOS app payment architecture

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, appstore-approval

everyone. I'm building an iOS app which is a platform for users and influencers.
They can exchange their experience and knowledge. Users can buy gems for book chatting with influencers and influencers will get some gems after finishing users' requests.
The app provides messaging and video call for books.
So, seems to must use in-app purchase to let users buy gems.
The main issue is how the influencers will convert gems to real money.
I've checked stripe connect and I'm a newbie for it.
Already checked Airbnb and twitch model and not sure I'm on the right way.
Is there any better way of it?
What am I missing now? Any help will be welcomed!. Thanks.

Comment: While you must use IAP for people to buy gems, you will need to identify some payment processor that you can use to send money to people's bank accounts to send money to influencers. PayPal is one example, but there are others. Recommending tools is off-topic for stack overflow. You will need to handle payment in your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure but not certain if you're selling 'gems' in the app, you'll have to use Apple's In-App Payments which means you won't be able to use Stripe in the way you expect.

You probably should [reach out to Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) and ask them for guidance, and confirm this is something Stripe can support.